# CloudFormation: "The requested configuration is currently not supported"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a EC2 Instance using CloudFormation.
Following is my configuration file.

```
Description:  This script create EC2 with Public IP

Resources:

  EC2CloudFormation:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select 
        - '0'
        - !GetAZs ''
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref EC2CloudformationInstanceProfilee
      ImageId: 'ami-06f1fab1ab342f0f7'
      InstanceType: t2.medium
      KeyName: mykey
      NetworkInterfaces: 
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
          DeviceIndex: "0"
          GroupSet: 
            - 'sg-XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
          SubnetId: 'subnet-XXXXXXXXXXX'

  EC2Role:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: EC2CloudFormationRole
      Description: Role for CloudFormation EC2 Instance
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /

  EC2CloudformationInstanceProfilee:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile'
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - !Ref EC2Role

  EC2CloudFormationPolicies:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
    Properties:
      PolicyName: EC2CloudFormationPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Sid: Stmt1566203227305
            Action:
              - 'cloudformation:*'
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: '*'
      Roles:
        - !Ref EC2Role
```

But I am facing the following error :

```
The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: Unsupported; Request ID: c7edeeb4-14e1-48b3-a90a-4ea79498b1e8)
```

I am not able to understand root cause of the issue.
The other resources ( Role, Instance Profile and Policy ) are getting created only `EC2::Instance` is not getting created.

Comment: Try it with a different AMI. See if you get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template worked perfectly fine for me.

I substituted:

- AMI (since yours is not public)
- Security Group
- Subnet (matching the first AZ)

It ran just fine, so your issue is likely to be one of the above.

Comment: Yes, the AMI ID  I was referring to was 64-bit Arm and those are supported with other instance types ( A series ). Thank you. But I would like to understand what is Arm types and normally they are not supported by all types of instances.

Comment: From [Amazon EC2 Instance Types - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/): _Amazon EC2 A1 instances deliver significant cost savings and are ideally suited for scale-out and Arm-based workloads that are supported by the extensive Arm ecosystem. A1 instances are the first EC2 instances powered by AWS Graviton Processors that feature 64-bit Arm Neoverse cores and custom silicon designed by AWS._